# Перестановочный шифр на C#

Tags: c#, шифрование

В перестановочных шифрах меняется порядок следования символов. В простом перестановочном шифре в качестве ключа выбирается перестановка чисел от 0 до n. Например, для n=7 можно использовать перестановку 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1. Далее текст записывается в n столбцов, которые затем переставляются в соответствии с порядком задаваемым перестановкой. Ниже приведён пример:

> `как вид`
>
> `но, сов`

Результат:

> `даквки`
>
> `вонс,о`

То есть, в ключе 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1 указывается, на каком месте будет стоять буква. Первая буква "к", ей соответствует цифра 3 и т.д.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать.

```
public string Encrypt(string msg, char[] key)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string[] msgInArray = new string[(msg.Length / key.Length) + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < (msg.Length / key.Length) + 1; i++)
    {
        if (msg.Length <= key.Length)
        {
            msgInArray[i] = msg;

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            msgInArray[i] = msg.Substring(i * key.Length, key.Length);
        }
    }

    int[] a = new int[key.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = key[i]-48;
    }

    List<char> msgl = new List<char>();

    for (int i = 0; i < msgInArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (msgInArray[i] != null)
        {
            msgl = msgInArray[i].ToList<char>();

            for (int j = 0; j < key.Length; j++)
            {
                result += msgl[a[j]];
            }
            msgl.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Encrypt(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text.ToCharArray()));
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> `Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке.
> Имя параметра: length`

в строке

```
msgInArray[i] = msg.Substring(i * key.Length, key.Length);
```

Comment: @Елена1234, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: >Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке

походу

    msg.Substring(i * key.Length, key.Length);

выходит за пределы строки, если трока не кратна `key.Length`

Answer (score 4):

Сезон "помогите сделать лабораторную работу" объявляется открытым.

Покажу, как преобразовать одну строку, дальше сами:

```
var source = "как вид"; 
var shift = new int[]{3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 1};
shift
    .Zip(source, (idx, ch)=>new {idx, ch})
    .OrderBy(x=>x.idx)
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, el)=>acc+el.ch);
// даквки
```

Comment: я вставила свой код

Comment: Злой вы, студентов лямбдами пугать. ))

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите уже существующий код для перестановочного шифратора, так будет проще понять и разобраться: [Classical Encryption Techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63432/Classical-Encryption-Techniques) (смотреть Transposition/Permutation).

Answer (score 0):

```
msgInArray[i] = msg.Substring(i * key.Length, key.Length);
```

`i * key.Length` - это стартовый индекс

`key.Length` - это длина на которую из `msg` ты вынимаешь строку